# Как правильно синхронизировать доступ к коллекции многими потоками

Tags: java, многопоточность, синхронизация

Моих знаний и опыта хватает, чтобы сделать так. Правильно ли это? Может есть какие-нибудь более элегантные решения?

```
private List<Connection> l =  Collections.synchronizedList(
                                  new ArrayList<>());

synchronized void m(String t) {
    l.forEach(v -> v.outputStream.println(t));
}
```

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp07233/

Comment: Сильно зависит от условий. как изменяется коллекция, элементы добавляется единоразово, редко или часто?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, эта коллекция хранит список пользователей, которые подключены к серверу.

Comment: В вашем случае для итерации гораздо более правильно использовать не `synchronized`-метод, а `synchronized(l) {...}` блок.

Comment: @Roman, почему IDE выдает подсказку при таком способе, что "synchronization on a non-final field". "Reports synchronized statements where the lock expression is a reference to a non-final field. Such statements are unlikely to have useful semantics, as different threads may be locking on different objects even when operating on the same object".

Comment: Ну там всё сказано. Т.к. поле не `final`, кто-то может его поменять, и окажется, что разные потоки работают с разными коллекциями, а не с одной и той же.

Comment: @Roman, Но ведь синхронизацию используем, чтобы этого не произошло.

Comment: Лучше объявить поле, как private final `List<Connection> l = Collections.synchronizedList(
                                  new ArrayList<>())`, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Всё гораздо сложней, чем "синхронизацию используем". Почитайте про [java memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html), в двух словах этого не объяснишь. А поле лучше сделать `final`, да.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Главное правило -- синхронизировать **любой** доступ к ресурсу (в данном случае коллекции), будь то чтение или запись. Как именно -- на первых порах не столько важно. Методы-обертки с модификатором `synchronizhed` -- как один из вариантов. Чем больше опыт работы с многопоточностью -- тем больше вариантов, в зависимости от требований.

Также нужно помнить, что даже специализированные потокобезопасные коллекции (из `java.util.concurrent.*`) при определенных сценариях тоже могут нуждаться в дополнительной синхронизации.

Comment: Т. е. если, у меня в коде используется добавление и удаление из коллекции через add() и remove(), потом где-то используется доступ к коллекции или какие-нибудь другие манипуляции, то я должен использовать синхронизацию во всех местах, где происходят какие-либо действия с коллекцией?

Comment: @jisecayeyo в вашем случае (использование synchronized обертки) дополнительно синхронизировать вызовы add() и remove() не надо, только итерацию. В общем же случае все зависит от типа  используемой коллекции и сценариев.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List):

> Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) list backed by the specified
>   list. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that **all**
>   access to the backing list is accomplished through the returned list.

Даже используя `synchronizedList`, операции по работе с возвращенной коллекцией всё равно надо заворачивать в `synchronized`.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае, мне кажется лучше использовать специализированную thread-safe структуру данных, например `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet` - будет меньше блокировок.